# const overloaded operator[] function and its invocation

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I define two versions of overloaded `operator[]` function in a class `array`. `ptr` is a pointer to first element of the `array` object.

```
int& array::operator[] (int sub) {  
   return ptr[sub];
}
```

and

```
int array::operator[] (int sub) const { 
  return ptr[sub];
}
```

Now, if I define a const object `integer1` the second function can only be called..... but if I make a non-const object and then invoke as below:

```
cout << "3rd value is" << integer1[2];
```

which function is called here?

Comment: For a `const` object or access path, the `const` function is invoked. Otherwise, non-const is invoked. `array` might not be a good choice of class name because there is a `std::array` template in the new C++11 standard.

Comment: Just an observation. It is better if you return const reference from the const version. See the declaration of *std::vector::operator[]* for an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second example, the non-const version will be called, because no conversion is required, and a call that requires no conversion is a better match than one that requires a conversion.

Ultimately, however, you have a basic problem here: what you really want is behavior that changes depending on whether you're using your object as an rvalue or an lvalue, and `const` doesn't really do that. To make it work correctly, you normally want to return a proxy object, and overload `operator=` and `operator T` for the proxy object:

```
template <class T>
class myarray { 
    T *ptr;

    class proxy { 
        T &val;
        proxy &operator=(proxy const &p); // assignment not allowed.
    public:
        proxy(T &t) : val(t) {}
        operator T() const { return val; }
        proxy &operator=(T const&t) { val = t; return *this; }
    };

    proxy const operator[](int sub) const { return proxy(ptr[sub]); }
    proxy operator[](int sub) { return proxy(ptr[sub]); }
    // obviously other stuff like ctors needed.
};
```

Now we get sane behavior -- when/if our `array<int>` (or whatever type) is const, our `operator[] const` will be used, and it'll give a `const proxy`. Since its assignment operators are *not* const, attempting to use them will fail (won't compile).

OTOH, if the original `array<int>` was not const, we'll get a non-const proxy, in which case we can use both `operator T` and `operator=`, and be able to both read and write the value in the `array<int>`.

Comment: This has the same problem as the original solution- if you want to do, say, `object[1].swap(object[2]);`, firstly, the syntax will be wrong because `proxy<T>` does not define that function, even if `T` does, and secondly, you're needlessly copying `object[2]` because you don't return a reference- even if `proxy` is non-const.

Comment: coffin what is the conversion, u are talking about in const version

Comment: @avinash: conversion from `myarray &` to `myarray const &`. It can be done implicitly, but it's still not as good of a match as doing no conversion.

Answer (score 2):

Your const version should return `const int&` not `int`, so that the semantics are *just the same* between the two functions.

Once you've done that, it *doesn't matter* which one is used. If the `const` version has to be used because your object has a const context, then it will be... and it won't matter as you're not trying to modify anything. Otherwise, it'll use the non-`const` version... but with just the same effect.

Comment: I disagree. I see no benefit in returning a `const int&` compared to an `int`.

Comment: @FredOverflow: Symmetry, is all. And I would not expect to be able to modify the result of `operator[]` on a `const` object (even if it's just a copy): that would be misleading.

Comment: You cannot modify the result of a function that returns a scalar by value. You get back a *value*, not a temporary object.

Comment: @FredOverflow: What? If I have `T const obj;` and I can write `obj[3] = 4;` because I'm using an `op[]` that returns by value, then that's confusing. I'd expect `op[]` to return a `ref-to-const` so that I can't perform that assignment.

Comment: @FredOverflow: Actually, I guess that wouldn't be an lvalue, would it? So I couldn't do the assignment and it wouldn't matter.. hmm. (I still like the symmetry of returning `ref` from non-`const` `op[]`, and `ref-to-const` from `const` `op[]`, though.)

Comment: You could do the assignment if you returned a class type, but `int` is a scalar.

Comment: It should be a `const T&`, because class types may not be copyable or copying may be expensive.

Comment: @DeadMG: Agreed. Unless you know for a fact that `T` will be a scalar, prefer `T const&`.

Comment: @FredOverflow I agree with Tomalak, because there's this: #1 `array a; a[0] = 0; int& i = a[0]; a[0] = 5; /* i is now 5 */`, #2 `array a; a[0] = 0; const int& i = static_cast<const array&>(a)[0]; a[0] = 5; /* i is now 5 */` I think #1 and #2 should behave the same.

Comment: I'm with @Fred on this. It's just like it is with [function parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139224/2139254#2139254): you pass by const reference unless they are built-ins, which are passed by value. Temporaries of built-in have very little detectable difference to const references (both can't be modified, both bind to a const ref), and returning them might be more efficient than returning a reference. So for the sake of symmetry (with function parameters), `operator[]() const` [should return built-ins by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/4421719#4421719).

Comment: @GMan: That's a pretty nasty piece of code. If I have a `const T&`, it might refer to an actual lvalue or it might refer to an rvalue. You never know, and you can't rely on either assumption. The same goes for `const T& foobar = foo.bar()`: Might `foobar` change through any side-effects in code between its initialization and any later evaluation? You don't know unless you look closely at `Foo::f()`. And whether that returns a reference to an lvalue or an rvalue is usually considered an implementation detail.

Comment: @sbi It's nasty yes, but if we consider `const int&` and `int` equal, it might just tip the scales to prefer the former. But perhaps I agree, relying on such stuff is bad design anyway.

Comment: @Dead: But we are *not* talking about class types, we are talking about `int` :) Of course you are right, in the general case it should be `const T&`, but we know that `int` is copyable, so returning by value is fine.

Comment: @sbi: I think that symmetry between functions that are defined _right next to each other_, do _the same thing_ and _have the same name_ is more important than symmetry with a different part of the language.

Comment: @Tomalak: Symmetry is in the eye of the beholder. One could argue that `int& f()` and `int f() const` are just as symmetric. Or that return type and parameters are _very_ close. I'm fine with your POV onto this, but you will have to accept that it's not  the only one.

Comment: @Tomalak: I know. This is what triggered my arguing. `:)`