# overload assignment and round bracket operator in C++

Tags: c++, function-call-operator

I want to define a class myVector that support both assignment `operator=` and bracket access e.g `myclass(1) = 0.5`. See a dummy example below

```
class myVector
{
public:
    vector<double> _v;
    myVector(unsigned int size) : _v(size, 0) { }

    double& operator()(int i)
    {
        return _v[i];
    }

    unsigned int size() const { return _v.size(); }

    myVector& operator=(const myVector& v)
    {
        _v.resize(v.size());
        for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++)
            _v[i] = v(i);
    }
}
```

This code cannot be compiled since `()` is not defined as a constant function. This is because I want to enable direct assignment such as `myvector(1) = 2`. To solve this problem, I can only think of two solutions. One is to define sth. like `double getValue(int i) const` but this seems weird since some duplicate code is added. The other is to remove `const` from the signature of `()` function, but that is undesirable as well. I am sure there will be a good work around but I cannot find it.

Comment: Why so complicated -  you can just say `_v = v;`, or `_v.swap(v);`.

Comment: those round brackets are called "parentheses", and the operator is called "the function call operator"

Comment: This is nearly an exact duplicate of an earlier question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762042/const-overloaded-operator-function-and-its-invocation/5762323. [My answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5762323/179910) to that applies here as well.

Answer (score 2):

The correct solution is "both".  Member functions, including operators, can be overloaded on `const`-ness (the `this` pointer is effectively a parameter and takes part in overload resolution).

```
double& operator()(int i) { return _v[i]; }
double operator()(int i) const { return _v[i]; }
```

NOTE: With non-member operators, the left-hand object isn't just like a parameter, it IS a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

For the particular case of the operator(), you should just provide two overloads:

```
double& operator()( int i ) { return _v[i]; }
double operator()( int i ) const { return _v[i]; } // [1]
```

If this was a templated container, the second overload would return a `const&`, but given that it is a `double`, returning a copy is fine.

Now as a recommendation, you can implement the *copy constructor*, and then implement a simple `swap` function:

```
void myVector::swap( myVector & lhs ) {
   _v.swap( lhs._v );
}
```

With those two tools in place, then you can use the idiomatic implementation of `operator=`:

```
myVector& myVector::operator=( myVector rhs ) { // by value
   swap( *this, rhs );
   return *this;
}
```

The other thing is that it does not make sense to roll your own loop to copy the vectors, they already know how to do that by themselves, so `_v = v._v;` has the same effect as your loop.